# Finding the variance of number of days to freedom

Tags: probability-theory

Someone is trapped in a cell containing three doors. The first  door leads to a tunnel that leads to the cell after two days of travel. The second leads to a tunnel that returns to the cell after three days of travel. The third door leads to freedom immediately. Assuming that the prisoner is always equally likely to choose among the doors that he has not previously chosen, what is the variance of the number of days until freedom?

My attempt is:
Let $N$ be the number of days until freedom, $N_i$ is number of additional days spent if he took door $i$ initially and let $Y$ be the door he takes initially.

$\mathrm{Var}(N)= \mathbb{E}(N^2) - \mathbb{E}(N)$

I computed $\mathbb{E}(n)$ to be $2.5$ $^{(\star)}$.

Now I'm not sure how to compute $\mathbb{E}(N^2)$.
$$
\mathbb{E}(N^2) = \mathbb{E}(N^2|Y=1)\mathbb{P}(Y=1) + \mathbb{E}(N^2|Y=2)\mathbb{P}(Y=2) + \mathbb{E}(N^2|Y=3)\mathbb{P}(Y=3) \\ = \frac{1}{3} \left(\mathbb{E}(N^2|Y=1) + \mathbb{E}(N^2|Y=2) + \mathbb{E}(N^2|Y=3)\right) $$

And I can't go from here.

$$^{(\star)}: \mathbb{E}(N) = \mathbb{E}(N|Y=1)\mathbb{P}(Y=1) + \mathbb{E}(N|Y=2)\mathbb{P}(Y=2) + \mathbb{E}(N|Y=3)\mathbb{P}(Y=3) \\ = \frac{1}{3}\left( \mathbb{E}(N|Y=1) + \mathbb{E}(N|Y=2) + \mathbb{E}(N|Y=3)\right)\\ = \frac{1}{3}(2 + \mathbb{E}(N_1) + 3 + \mathbb{E}(N_2) + 0 + \mathbb{E}(N_3))  
$$
where
$$\mathbb{E}(N_1) = 3/2, \mathbb{E}(N_2) = 1,\mathbb{E}(N_3) = 0.
$$

Comment: There are only four different possible outcomes for the number of days before getting out: $0, 2, 3, 5$. Can you compute probability of each outcome?

Comment: To the 0,1,3,5 outcomes, $\frac13,\frac16,\frac16,\frac26$ belong as probabilities, respectively. The mean is ... The variance is ...

Comment: That worked. Is there a way to use my method? (How would I compute E(N^2 |Y=1) etc?)